# IIS Api Versioning

Tags: api, iis, version

I currently have a .net 4.5 web api (versions 1,2,3) being served from an IIS box. Its host url is https://api.company.com/. The versioning is handled via url and the controllers are segregated using the api/v1/*, ap1/v2/* and api/v3/*.

I have a new version of the web api using .net core 3.1. The requirement is to have it;s url handle the api/v4/* requests.

I would like to serve the new web api from the same IIS box.

My question is how do do this? What do I need to setup and how must I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you configure IIS as reverse proxy, then any URL pattern is easy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: you could try to host as the application under the https://api.company.com/ site. create a different application pool and choose that for the application.